# How to ignore default start up code and linker script in the compiler

Tags: linker, startup

Currently, I try to compile my code on SPC58 board, powerpc. I use Green Hill and Wind river (Diab) compilers. 
* I write myself a startup code crt0.c file, my entry point is _start 
When I compile my code it said the symbol multiply defined in 
D:\compiler\ghs\PPC\comp_201914\lib\ppc\crt0.o
It looks like my installation folder for Green Hill compiler already have startup code. (I guess crt0.o here is the default startup code)
I would like my compiler to ignore default startup code and take my written startup code crt0.c instead. How can I do that? also I have a doubt why do we have the default startup code here? because we may use the same compiler for different boards, the startup code for different board my be different.

When I install Diab compiler, and write my linker script. When compiling and linking. it also reports that defaultvle.dld (the linker script already exist in the installation folder) If I write a new linker script, it said I just redefine the whole thing in default linker script. 
I may misunderstand something here.

Answer (score 0):

For diab compiler you can use -Wm newLinkerScript(the -Wm will ignore the default linker script) and the -Ws to ignore the default start-up code.